# Google Analytics reports to be receiving data, but none is showing up

Tags: google-analytics

Hi recently redesigned my site (http://bit.ly/gwrYwb) which was formerly tracking pageviews properly via Google Analytics. After the redesign, I inserted the exact same code right before the `</head>` tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
```

(The UA number is correct on the actual page.) However, GA is mysteriously reporting zero pageviews/visits, even though it claims to be receiving data. Has anyone experienced a problem like this before? The only other JS I'm using is including jQuery, as well as a widely-used jQuery plugin on one of my pages.

Comment: Did you allow 24 hours for results to propagate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of lame, but have you checked your profile filters? You might still have old filters (for the former website) applied that filter all urls out. 
We had this problem with another website and were debugging for weeks until we found this simple solution...